# Felixge/Node-Mysql Separate Connection File

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, node.js

I am attempting to use felixge/node-mysql in Node for my node app.
However, instead of the usual

```
mysql.createConnection(...)
```

in the app.js, I wanted it separate as a "config" file.
Right now in my config.js it is:

```
function localConnect(){
    //Node Mysql dependency npm install mysql@2.0.0-alpha7
    return require('mysql').createConnection({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database'
    });
}
```

and in app js:

```
...
//Node Mysql dependency npm install mysql@2.0.0-alpha7
var mysql = require('mysql');
//MYSQL database config file
var connection = require('./config.js').localConnect();
connection.connect();
```

and connection.connect() fails.

The purpose is so that I can commit it to my repo without exposing my DB connection info and still provide a dbSample file for the user incase they wish to use it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: May be a silly question, but are you exporting the localConnect() function from the config?

Comment: Not a silly question at all, that was what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about exporting in Node so as per Nick's hint, the following code works for config.js:

```
var mysql = function localConnect(){
    //Node Mysql dependency npm install mysql@2.0.0-alpha7
    return require('mysql').createConnection({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database'
    });
}
module.exports.localConnect = mysql;
```

In the app.js:

```
//MYSQL database config file
var connection = require('./config.js').localConnect();
connection.connect(); //Successful
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

db-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  user: 'username',
  ...
};
```

db.js

```
var config = require('./db-config');

module.exports = require('mysql').createConnection(config);
```

app.js

```
var db = require('./db.js');
db.query('SELECT ?', [ 1 ], function (err, data) { ... });
```